# Fetch Google analytics user explorer Data via API Call

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

How can i fetch data from google analytics user explorer using API?

I need to get the detail data of each user and find out that google google analytic can display that data in user explorer, I have tried Analytics Data API but it only returns aggregated data.

Comment: What is google analytics user explorer?

Comment: it's the user explore report on GA4

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like raw data?

If yes. Then the best place you need to check is BigQuery.

But first is did you set up the integration with the GA4 and BigQuery?

Once it is done. The raw data will be store in BigQuery and you can fetch the data there using SQL like language.

Comment: There asking for an api call.   The Big Query export configuration is not an api call.   Also you seam to have more questions in your answer then answers.   Maybe this should have been a comment until the question was more clear.

Comment: I need to track the detail activities of an user, first i have discovered that the user explorer report might have the data i need. If i can derive user activity from raw data then i can take this approach. Like @Linda Lawton said, does BigQuery support for fetching data programmatically?

Comment: Currently GA4 Data API does not support providing the data that you see in the `user explorer` report. Of course you can get the data in BigQuery with coding. BigQuery just like a database. Again you need to integrate it in your GA4 admin. After that the raw data will flow into BigQuery.

Comment: I have linked GA4 to google BigQuery, but it only load data starting from the linking moment. Do you know how to load history raw data of GA4 to BigQuery?